How to add feature to admin js corectly
AdminJS is now only ESM-only compatible (V7 Version), how to register feature Mongoose , The documentation said
const adminjsUploadFeature = await import('@adminjs/upload');
but I don't know where I should use it
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { User } from './user/user.schema';

const DEFAULT_ADMIN = {
  email: 'root@root.com',
  password: 'root',
};

const authenticate = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  if (email === DEFAULT_ADMIN.email && password === DEFAULT_ADMIN.password) {
    return Promise.resolve(DEFAULT_ADMIN);
  }
  return null;
};

const usersNavigation = {
  name: 'Users',
  icon: 'User',
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/admin-panel'),
    UserModule,
    import('@adminjs/nestjs').then(({ AdminModule }) =>
      AdminModule.createAdminAsync({
        useFactory: async () => {
          const adminjsMongooseFeature = await import('@adminjs/mongoose'); // where should I use Mongoose?

          return {
            adminJsOptions: {
              rootPath: '/admin',
              resources: [],
            },
            resources: [
              {
                resource: User,
                options: {
                  navigation: usersNavigation,
                },
              },
            ],
          };
        },
      }),
    ),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

